# Google Data Studio - Sum of 2 fields from different data sources

Tags: google-sheets, worksheet-function, google-data-studio

I'm just getting started with Google Data Studio. I have connected 2 different Shopify stores to it, which worked totally fine.

Now I try to show the sum of the revenue of both stores, but the calculated field option only let me choose the field of 1 store connected.

How can I create the sum of the revenue field of 2 different data sources?

Answer (score 1):

I was also wanting to add the same data element, Total Unique Searches, for different sources and here is how I solved it:

1. Click on Resource at the top and then select Manage Blended Data
2. Edit your Blended Data
3. For each of the data elements you want to sum, click on edit and give it a unique name, e.g. Total Unique Searches A and then the next one rename to Total Unique Searches B, and so on for all of your data sources
4. Save changes
5. Add a new field and in the formula sum up the renamed data elements:
   Total Unique Searches A  + Total Unique Searches B
   (previously you could only select Total Unique Searches)

Answer (score 0):

1. Insert a first `scorecard` with Shopify n°1  as a `data source`.
2. Insert a second `scorecard` with Shopify n°2 as a `data source`
3. Select both > Right-click > `Blend data`

> You create a blended data source by joining the records in one data source to the records of up to 4 other data sources. To join the data, each data source in the blend must share a set of **one or more dimensions**, known as a join key. Blended data sources include all the records from the leftmost data source in the Blend Data panel, and the records from the data sources to the right that share the same values across the join key.
>
> [How blending works - support.google.com](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420?hl=en#how-blending-works)